# FsCheck c# When property combinator

Tags: c#, fscheck

I'm trying to adopt fscheck, but have a very hard time as there is no much documentation for C#. Can you explain, why the following example of using When combinator for properties fails (evidently, I don't understand how to use it properly)?

```
 [Test]
    public void WherePorperty()
    {
      Prop.ForAll(NotNullString().ToArbitrary(), s=>s.StartsWith("A").When(s.StartsWith("A"))).VerboseCheckThrowOnFailure();
    }

    public Gen<string> NotNullString()
    {
      return Arb.Generate<string>().Where(s => s != null);
    }
```

Comment: Asking for examples is considered off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't actually really fail, it just says "Arguments exhausted after n tests".

When you use `When` FsCheck keeps track of how many generated values it has had to throw away because they don't satisfy the condition given in the `When`. By default this is 1000 values.

This indicates the condition is too stringent, the generator doesn't generate values that satisfy the `When` condition often enough.

It's just kind of a safety net so test time doesn't balloon, or the test gets stuck altogether.

By the way, this is explained here: https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/Properties.html#Conditional-Properties with a C# example.